# Database run in archive log mode

Tags: oracle

I'm using Oracle 11g on RHEL 5.
I've created one database with no archivelog.
After doing offline migration from SQLSERVER to ORACLE, I've changed this database to run in archive log mode.

My database is running normally and I'm sure that there is no change to the database, but I wonder why it generates many archive files (about 1GB a day).

Do you have any idea?

Regards,

Sarith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for a busy production database, 1GB of logs is quite small (I have databases with 100GB of logs or more per day).  Anyway, if you want to know, what is in the logs, you should have a look at the Oracle LogMiner:

http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/oracle/05-jul/o45dba.html

Jochen

Comment: Hi Jochen, I wonder why arhcive logs are generated if there is no change the my database?

Comment: Hello Sarith, every commit in the database generates a log - so I'm pretty sure there have been changes in the database.  May be there are running some internal jobs, or changes from remote systems.  A look into the logminer should give you some hints, where the changes are coming from.

Answer (score 1):

Archive Logs are the Oracle equivalent of the Transaction Log in SQLServer.
They should be a vital part of your backup strategy.

They are more correctly known as archived redo logs.

Oracle has a set of rotating log files that it uses to store the statements executed on the database. These existing in both archive and non archive mode.

In archive mode a redo log can only be reused once it has been archived.
These are the files that you are seeing.

I'd suggest using RMAN to manage both your backups and archive log maintenance.